# Java Ribbon - Active Project - Alternatives to flamingo

Tags: java, controls, ribbon, radiance-flamingo

I want to use a ribbon menu in java. I know there are several projects running which implements a ribbon menu. My problem is, that the most of them seams to be dead or at least won't get developed anymore. For example the flamingo project.

Does anyone know another project which implements a ribbon component for java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word - nope. Flamingo is the best option around in my opinion, and while it's not really developed by Krill anymore there is a new fork called insubstantial which maintains it. You can grab it [here](http://shemnon.com/speling/2011/04/insubstantial-62-release.html).

I'm using it in one of my applications, documentation isn't brilliant but once you've read [this](http://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial) and played around, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to use it. It does pretty much everything you'd need.

Is there any particular reason why you didn't want to use flamingo other than it hadn't been maintained in a while?

Comment: Flamingo was reanimated in December 2016, there were Maintenance Updates since February 2017 and now Flamingo is part of [Project Radiance](https://www.pushing-pixels.org/2018/05/23/hello-radiance.html).